# How can I find center position coordinates of text which created by canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, path, html5-canvas, coordinates

I want to find center position coordinates of text which created by canvas dynamically. For example, I want to find the x and y coordinates of the center of the number 2 text which written 600px with arial font-family,  at 50px intervals. Example:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "600px Arial";             // ** Font family and Font-Size Changeable
ctx.fillText('2',10,450);             // ** Number Changeable
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3cjbxqL/)

[image: sample image]

Text, font-family, and font-size changeable dynamically. How can I find center position coordinates

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on how you define the "center position" of a text. An approach could be to search for certain pixels that define the bounding-box of the text. This bounding-box is always a rectangle that has edges respectively min/max coordinates in each dimension (x, y).

[image]

So the center of a text could be defined as the center of this bounding-box. This is what `getCenterCoordsFromText` does, it returns centered x/y-coordinates based on the coordinate-system of the bounding-box or of the whole canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.font = "100px Arial";
ctx.fillText("2", 14, 92);

function getCenterCoordsFromText(colors, relativeToCanvas) {
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var minX = Infinity;
    var minY = Infinity;
    var maxX = 0;
    var maxY = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        var x = (i / 4) % canvas.width;
        var y = Math.floor((i / 4) / canvas.width);
        var pixelFound = data[i] === colors.red &&
            data[i + 1] === colors.green &&
            data[i + 2] === colors.blue &&
            data[i + 3] === colors.alpha;
        if (pixelFound) {
            if (minY > y) {
                minY = y;
            }
            if (maxY < y) {
                maxY = y;
            }
            if (minX > x) {
                minX = x;
            }
            if (maxX < x) {
                maxX = x;
            }
        }

    }
    var middleX = (maxX - minX) / 2;
    var middleY = (maxY - minY) / 2;
    return {
        x: (relativeToCanvas ? minX : 0) + middleX,
        y: (relativeToCanvas ? minY : 0) + middleY,
        offsetX: relativeToCanvas ? minX : 0,
        offsetY: relativeToCanvas ? minY : 0
    }
}

// get locally centered coordinates within bounding-box 
var relToCanvasCoordSystem = false;
var letterCoordRelToBox = getCenterCoordsFromText({
    red: 0,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0,
    alpha: 255 
}, relToCanvasCoordSystem);
document.getElementById("relBoundingBoxCoord").innerHTML = 'x: ' + letterCoordRelToBox.x + ' y: ' + letterCoordRelToBox.y;

// get globally centered coordinates of the bounding-box based on the whole canvas
relToCanvasCoordSystem = true;
var letterCoordRelToCanvas = getCenterCoordsFromText({
    red: 0,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0,
    alpha: 255 
}, relToCanvasCoordSystem);
document.getElementById("relCanvasCoord").innerHTML = 'x: ' + letterCoordRelToCanvas.x + ' y: ' + letterCoordRelToCanvas.y;

// draw a colored reference for bounding-box-coordinates-system note
function drawBoundingBox(offsetX, offsetY, width, height){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    ctx.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY);
    ctx.stroke(); 
    ctx.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY + height);
    ctx.stroke(); 
    ctx.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY + height);
    ctx.stroke(); 
    ctx.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var offsetX = letterCoordRelToCanvas.offsetX;
var offsetY = letterCoordRelToCanvas.offsetY;
var boxWidth = letterCoordRelToBox.x*2;
var boxHeight = letterCoordRelToBox.y*2;
drawBoundingBox(offsetX, offsetY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
}

.bbcs{
  color: red;
}

.ccs{
  color: #a3a3a3;
}
```

```html
<p>relative to <span class="bbcs">bounding-box-coordinate-system</span>:</p>
<div id="relBoundingBoxCoord"></div>
<p>relative to <span class="ccs">canvas-coordinate-system</span>:</p>
<div id="relCanvasCoord"></div>
<br/>

<canvas id="canvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: For now it seems to be the best way. However let's hope  the measureText() method will be improved soon : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-measuretext

Comment: Yes, I have also considered to use `measureText` but it's still to vague.